# How to make an item appear in two groups in a list view?

Tags: list-view, grouping

Say I have these items on a list.

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Yellow
- Red

I want to create a view where the items are grouped by the "attribute" column.

**Fruit ▼**

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange

**Colour** ▼

- Orange
- Yellow
- Red

But Sharepoint (2013) won't let me pick the "attribute" column when I go in the "Modify View > Group by" settings. Is there any way to modify the list to achieve this without having duplicates of the "Orange" item?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am searching a solution .

Comment: Basically what I ended up doing was creating different views for each attribute(filter on one attribute only) and add them one below the other on a page with 'List view' webparts. I added a custom script so that the webparts are minimized by default and only expand when clicked to mimic how the native 'Group by' view.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are looking to create a "Group By" view and allow the column that items are being grouped by to have multiple values for each item. To the best of my knowledge that can't be done, but there might be a work-around that I am unaware of

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot group by multiple columns on a single Group By level.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what I ended up doing was creating different views for each attribute(filter on one attribute only) and add them one below the other on a page with 'List view' webparts. I added a custom script so that the webparts are minimized by default and only expand when clicked to mimic how the native 'Group by' view.